# Subversion: how to preserve a semicolon in ~/.subversion/config as parameter, e.g. for tunnels.ssh?

Tags: windows, svn, config

In the Subversion `config` file, I have to pass a **Java classpath** to a custom SSH executable which is a **Windows batch file**. The classpath contains semicolons to separate path entries. However, at the batch file, only the first entry of the classpath arrives. Subsequent entries are passed in one-by-one as additional parameters. Example:

Subversion's `config` file contains:

```
ssh=d:\\temp\\ssh.bat "1\;2;3"
```

The content of `d:\temp\ssh.bat` is:

```
echo %1-%2-%3 > d:\temp\ssh.out
```

After invoking `svn up` in a working copy connected via `svn+ssh`-protocol, the content of `d:\temp\ssh.out` is:

```
1-2-3
```

However, I would expect:

```
1;2;3--
```

Tested on Windows, with *svn, version 1.8.4 (r1534716)*

Comment: Does placing a backslash in front of the semicolons help?

Comment: @DavidW. unfortunately, no.

Comment: And, I take it colons instead of semicolons don't work. Can you take your entire tunnel command and put it into a batch file? You may have to use `cmd.exe -c my.bat` in your `config` file. All the config file is doing is passing that command onward to the shell.

Comment: Colons in the CLASSPATH would only work on Linux, not on Windows. We had troubles earlier when creating temporary batch files due to file system permissions on Linux (e.g. on certain systems you can't create a file in /tmp with the executable bit set for security reasons), so that's why I would prefer to pass all I need in as parameters and thus I'm looking for a way to get that working with `.svn/config`.

Comment: No: Make the tunnel command a BATCH script on your Windows system, and in your `.config` call that BATCH script to execute your custom SSH command. Your Windows will execute it. If you can execute that batch script on the command line, you can execute it in the `.config` file too. (Although you may have to prefix it with `cmd.exe /c`).

Comment: Problem is that the CLASSPATH is a dynamic one, so it has to be passed to the BATCH script. I'm using JavaHL here and it allows to inject an arbitrary `tunnels.ssh`. This is where I have added the CLASSPATH.

Comment: This is getting curiouser and curiouser... Are you passing `%CLASSPATH%`, or do you manually create the CLASSPATH each time you do the tunnel? Could you use a script that allows you to pass CLASSPATH with colons or some other character, then the script replaces those characters with semicolons before calling the actual tunnel command. On Unix, you could use `sed`, but if you were on Unix, you wouldn't have this colon/semicolon issue. The `for /F` Windows batch can be used to replace the selected characters with semicolons. Type `help for` to see how to use this.

Comment: @DavidW. it's a custom classpath. I agree, that using another character and replacing that one in the script would work, but I was hoping that there is a simple solution to make Subversion avoid interpreting ";" as separator.

Comment: It's the way the .config file is parsed. This is a INI file, and in INI files, semicolons are comment characters. Hmmm... What if you put the CLASSPATH value in quotes? That might prevent the semicolon from being interpreted as a comment character, and the quotes won't be taken as part of the parameter value.

Comment: @DavidW. unfortunately neither commenting nor escaping ";" helps. So it looks like Subversion does not have the most elaborate INI file parser. I've now resorted to creating a dynamic script. Thanks a lot for your help. Of course, I'd accept an "It's not possible with Subversion 1.8" answer.

Comment: I don't even understand why you're having this problem.  Semicolon has no special meaning in Subversion config files.  Based on your mention of SSH I can only assume that you're trying to setup a tunnel agent.  Can you provide an example of what you've put in the svn config file?

Comment: @BenReser, exactly, I'm trying to invoke a `java` SSH tunnel. I've added an example illustrating the problem, especially that the semicolon seems to have some special meaning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue really a combination of Subversion (specifically the APR dependency we use for platform independence) and batch file quoting.

First of all the problem here is that semicolons (;) are treated specially by batch files when processing the arguments.  Specifically unless the [argument is surrounded by double quotes (") it is replaced by a space (see the delimiters section of at the link)](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/parameters.php).  Now you clearly have a double quote surrounding your argument so it should work.

However, Subversion uses the [apr_tokenize_to_argv()](https://apr.apache.org/docs/apr/1.5/group__apr__strings.html#ga5213cee7e8ba799df9dc2e57f71cd4dd) function from APR (to split the configured value into separate arguments).  As part of doing that it ends up removing your quotes (though it pays attention to them to avoid splitting arguments that contain spaces).  It does however let you escape the quotes in which case it ignores them and just passes them on through.

So setting your configuration like so:

```
ssh=d:\\temp\\ssh.bat \"1;2;3\"
```

should make it behave as you'd expect.  Now that does mean that %1 will include the quotes, but hopefully Java is ok with that.

Comment: Thanks! From giving it a short try, this seems to work with Java.